# GRASS GIS problem with r.in.pdal

Tags: grass-gis, laz

I tried to import .laz files with:

```
for mydom in $(ls *.laz) ; do r.in.pdal input=$mydom output=$(basename $mydom .laz) method=percentile pth=90; done
```

and got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/.grass7/addons/scripts/r.in.pdal", line 532, in <module>
    main()
  File "//.grass7/addons/scripts/r.in.pdal", line 464, in main
    command_pdal1.extend(['pipeline', '--input', tmp_file_json2])
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'tmp_file_json2' referenced before assignment
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you spotted a bug which we have fixed a few days ago ([commit reference](https://github.com/OSGeo/grass-addons/commit/94b4e26c938d745298f7e1b5e7aa88d4dc899097)).

Simply reinstall the r.in.pdal command with g.extension to fetch the updated version.